# recursive regex for matching bracket pairs in gnu r

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am experimenting with a recursive regex in R and the stringr package. Somehow it gives me an syntax error: U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX

The regex is working correctly and matches only the matching brackets:

https://regex101.com/r/Uv9Xy4/1

But in R it gives me said syntax error:

```
str_extract("((blub))(", "(?s)\\((?:[^()]+|(?R))*+\\)")
```

Am I missing the escape of any control character?

Comment: ICU is not PCRE. It does not support recursion.

Comment: Why not write a rudimentary parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ICU regex library used in `stringr` is not capable of everything PCRE can do. ICU regex engine does not support recursion.

So, use base R with `perl=TRUE`:

```
x <- "((blub))("
regmatches(x, regexpr("\\((?:[^()]+|(?R))*+\\)", x, perl=TRUE))
## => [1] "((blub))"
```

Note that `(?s)` DOTALL modifier is redundant here since there is no `.` in the pattern and can safely be removed.